# Possible to disable the search system?

Tags: search

Wondering if it's possible to completely disable the search if the site doesn't need it. In WordPress I'm able to detect when `is_search()` and then setup a redirect, as well as a redirect in the search template as a backup.

Any way to do this easily in craft or just turn the search system off completely?

thanks

Comment: Craft doesn't include a default search page—are you looking to disable it in the control panel? In other words, a search feature won't exist on your site unless you create a template and query for entries in response to a form submission or URL pattern… Indexing is another matter—some of your content (i.e. titles) will be indexed no matter what, but you're able to control what custom fields get indexed!

Comment: Not the cp, the front end. If anyone can still type a query in the url, I'd like to prevent that. Some sites don't need a search, and some site owners don't want one.

Comment: Yeah, don't sweat it—in Craft, search is only a "feature" if you build it. It'll never disclose information about Entries/Categories/Assets/etc. unless you explicitly query  for and display them. There is a search index maintained in the database so that it's *possible* to search, but again, you have to actually implement a search form + results page to take advantage of it.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info, man. Much appreciated.

Comment: You got it. I'll think on how this can be transformed into a complete answer—if I ghost-edit your original question a bit, don't be alarmed! 

Comment: Dematerialize away.  